# Nest API: Has anyone found on required fields

Tags: nest-api

I have been looking through the nest docs and the only doc that I see around required fields is for the ETA model seen here:
https://developer.nest.com/documentation/eta-reference

Does anyone know if there is a page for the thermostats, structures and Nest protect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Matthew, 
The error code page shows (Example) that you must me in 'cool' or 'heat' mode to change the target temperature, and in 'heat-cool' mode to change the high and low settings.
Otherwise, you receive an error when you PUT your changes.

```
https://www.developer.nest.com/documentation/error-codes#eta
```

you saw these right?
    https : //www.developer.nest.com/documentation/away-guide
    https : //www.developer.nest.com/documentation/api#thermostats
    https : //www.developer.nest.com/documentation/api#smoke_co_alarms

Comment: Yes I did, I guess what I was looking for was a clearer way to define what is guaranteed to be in the response...and the enumeration (if applicable) of some of the fields in a more digestible format. But thank you, consider this answered.